# Expand the range of type data double in PHP

Tags: php

I need to do a precision calculation of double data type in PHP.
the number is bigger than E-320.

```
<?php
    $dob = 2.0750757125332E-320;
    echo $dob;
?>
```

The result in browser is

```
2.0750757125332E-320
```

but if I put the number example :
`$dob = 2.0750757125332E-350` The result is `0`.

Is there any way to expand the value of `$dob` ? I need do do a calculation > `nE-600`

Comment: You should be able to use [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) if it's available on your system. `phpinfo()` should tell you.